# Migrate Vanity Nameservers to AWS Route53?

Tags: dns, amazon-route53

I'm in the process of migrating a bunch of stuff over to AWS and I've hit a bit of a snag in relation to Route53, specifically with vanity nameservers.

Current setup (not on Route53);

- ns1.example.com - Glue records pointing to IP address of current DNS provider
- ns2.example.com - Glue records pointing to IP address of current DNS provider

Various domains, all set to ns1.example.com for their authorities nameservers at the registrar;

- website-one.com
- website-two.com
- etc.

So I've been doing some testing with getting this migrated to Route53, and I'm not sure this is straight forward to do when you want to use a single vanity nameserver across multiple domains. When I create 2x hosted zones in Route53, they get different nameservers that Route53 automatically generates, i.e.;

- example.com Hosted Zone - ns-123.awsdns-456.com
- website-one.com Hosted Zone - ns-789.awsdns-321.com
- website-two.com Hosted Zone - ns-987.awsdns-654.com
- etc.

As such, with there only being one option at the registrar for example.com to configure the Glue Records;

- ns1.example.com - pointing to IP Address of the Route53 nameserver, i.e. ns-123.awsdns-456.com (1.2.3.4)
- ns2.example.com - pointing to IP Address of the Route53 nameserver, i.e. ns-123.awsdns-456.net (1.2.3.4)

Then I'm a bit lost as to how you're supposed to get this kind of setup working in Route53.

The reason for wanting this is to avoid having to go messing around with the nameservers at all of the different domains, some of which I can easily access, others are a bit of a pain to get access to so they can be updated.

Thoughts on how to best approach this?

Comment: you need [reusable delegation set](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/create-reusable-delegation-set.html) (you can only create it using cli/api, there is no web UI for this)

Comment: Grrrr. Damn AWS and CLI/API for basic+ features (surely this isn't an advanced requirement these days). Looks like I'll be updating the Nameservers for the domains at the Registrar to the R53 ones. I came to the same conclusion after a lot of research + testing, just a shame this isn't easily supported at present. None the less, thanks for the confirmation @DusanBajic that's good to know that this is the only option - Especially since I've had no response on the AWS forums which is a disappointment from AWS.  (ps. if I could give point on a comment I would :-) )